# Bookmarks and configuration not saved in evince(Default Document Viewer)

Tags: configuration, evince

When I open a document in evince and read through some pages, close it and again reopen the same document in evince, it starts again from the first page. Even the bookmarks are not shown after reopening.
Please help.

I read a lot of big books and its a nightmare to find where I was last time.

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: I'm using 16.04.

Comment: I'm using the same 16.04. but here evince automatically opens on the page I opened last. Can you run `evince` in a terminal and show us the output?

Comment: when I wrote evince on the terminal and hit enter it showed the following message:

(evince:12658): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/sanjeev/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied

(evince:12658): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/sanjeev/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied

(evince:12658): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/sanjeev/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied

Comment: Check the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some unknown reason (may be running evince with root) some file's permission has been changed.

You need to execute these command to return back the ownership and the permission -

```
sudo chown sanjeev:sanjeev ~/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home
sudo chmod 600 ~/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home
```

That should fix the problem.

Comment: thank you very much it worked.
when I open it in terminal and saw the error I pretty much knew what had happened. The thought never occurred to me. Again thank you very much Anwar. It was bugging me for quite a long time and I even started using Okular but I always liked Evince more.

Comment: @gabs.1BB3 Glad it helped :)

Comment: I hit this page in a web search.  I'm experiencing the same problem (Linux version 4.8.0-41-generic (buildd@lgw01-18) (gcc version 6.2.0 20161005 (Ubuntu 6.2.0-5ubuntu12) ) #44-Ubuntu).  The directory is owned by me and I can create files via the shell, but evince reports an error with permissions.  evince is not itself setuid and I can think of no reason why it should have no access.  Any suggestions?

Comment: @FredDouglis have you tried the suggestion?

Comment: My permissions were already set that way.